# pagination in php not working

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am new to php. I have to display the records from mysql with pagination in php. In my code the records are fetching properly but pagination is not working.It is showing the page number if i click any page it shows the full record only.

**display.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<html>

<body>
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "", "task");

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $per_page= 30;
    $sql="SELECT * FROM data";
    $result= $conn->query($sql);


    if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])){
        $page=$_GET['page'];
    }
    else{
        $page = 1;
    }
    $start =($page - 1) * $per_page;
    $sql=$sql." LIMIT $start,$per_page";
    $query2 = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>  
    <tr>  
    <th>Ticket ID</th>  
    <th>Tocken Number</th>
    <th>Status</th>  
    </tr>  
<thead>  
<tbody>  
<?php  
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
?>  
            <tr>  
            <td><?php echo $row["ticket_id"]; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row["tocken_no"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["status"] ?></td>   
            </tr>  
<?php  
};  
?>  
</tbody>  
</table>  
<?php
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    $pages = ceil($row_cnt/$per_page);

$page_link="<div class='pagination'>";

for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{
$page_link .= "<a href='display.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
}
echo $page_link . "</div>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed single thing in your code, Change code from

```
<?php  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  ?>
```

to

```
<?php  while ($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()) {   ?> // $query2 you should pass the variable of limit query
```

This should work!